# Eclipse and WX compatibility issue

Tags: python, wxpython

I decided to give PyDev and Eclipse a try.

I have compatible version of Python (2.6.5) and wx, but when I try to run a program with PyDev/Eclipse I get the following error:

> import wx   File "/var/tmp/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-13~231/2.6/DSTROOT/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/**init**.py",
>   line 45, in    File
>   "/var/tmp/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-13~231/2.6/DSTROOT/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core.py",
>   line 4, in  ImportError:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/*core*.so:
>   no appropriate 64-bit architecture
>   (see "man python" for running in
>   32-bit mode)

I just don't understand why I would get an error while try to run a program under Eclipse, that I know would run if I ran it through say the terminal.

Comment: Have you tried running it through the terminal? It looks as if your error has to do with the wx core.so library file - specifically it looks as if you're running a 64-bit OS and the .so file was compiled for 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565201/wxpython-incompatible-with-snow-leopard) helpful.