# WxPython Incompatible With OS X?

Tags: python, eclipse, wxpython, pydev

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“no matching architecture in universal wrapper” problem in wxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606964/no-matching-architecture-in-universal-wrapper-problem-in-wxpython)

I am using OS X Snow Leopard and

I just start to learn python and

I am getting error to use wxpython.

What I did so far is...

First , I installed pydev for my eclipse

Second, I installed wxpython "wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.7"

I simply wanna run

to make sure it is working or not

however, i am getting error message

http://cfile4.uf.tistory.com/original/2010E9374F4A101A2FD80C

I was trying to follow what

[WxPython Incompatible With Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565201/wxpython-incompatible-with-snow-leopard)

but I am not really sure the ways that they did.(I kind of tried to it but it didn't work..)

Does anybody know the way to fix this problems ?

plus, there are two ver of wxpython on the web page

what's difference between wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.7 and wxPython2.8-osx-ansi-py2.7?

thanks

Comment: Your question isn't exactly readable. If a question is not-so-well written, chances are more people will give up reading it before they understand it, and have a chance to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed wxwidgets first?

The difference between wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.7 and wxPython2.8-osx-ansi-py2.7 is the encoding. I suggest the unicode.